# Run method on Java Runnable instance not called after ExecutorService.submit

Tags: java, runnable, executorservice

I have a program where I initialized a pool of threads using ExecutorService. From main application threads, I create a runnable instance with some data and pass it to threadpool using `executorservice.submit()`, one of the thread from the pool takes the data and posts it to Kafka. Same code is working fine on other machines( Machine 1: AIX - inside WebSphere Application Server, Machine 2: Windows 10, stand-alone java JVM ). 
When I run the same code inside stand-alone JVM on AIX it does not work(no logs from Runnable and data is also not posted to Kafka.

Classes:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionHandler;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;



public class CustomExecutorServiceWrapper {



private static ExecutorService[] executorArr =  {Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1),Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1),Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1),Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1),Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1),Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1),Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1), Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1),Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1),Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1) } ;

public static void submitToSpecificThread(Runnable r) {
        int i = r.hashCode()%10;
    ExecutorService executorService = executorArr[Math.abs(i)];
    ThreadPoolExecutor tPoolExecutor = (ThreadPoolExecutor)executorService;
     tPoolExecutor.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new RejectedExecutionHandler() {

        @Override
        public void rejectedExecution(Runnable r, ThreadPoolExecutor executor) {
            System.out.println("Task rejected" );

        }
    });
    System.out.println("Thread Name - "+Thread.currentThread().getId() +" " +  Thread.currentThread().getName() + " queue size " +  tPoolExecutor.getQueue().size() );
    Future fObj = executorService.submit(r);
    System.out.println("FutureObject Cancelled" + fObj.isCancelled());
    System.out.println("FutureObject isDone" + fObj.isDone());

    System.out.println("Thread Name - "+Thread.currentThread().getId() +" " +  Thread.currentThread().getName() + " after submit queue size " +
            tPoolExecutor.getQueue().size() );

}
}
```

Class - 2:

```
import com.common.kafka.StaticKafkaBaseSenderImpl;

public class CustomRunnable implements Runnable{

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return strWorkLoadIdentifier.hashCode();
    }

    String strWorkLoadIdentifier ;

    String strLoadMessage ;

    private void log(String str) {
        System.out.println("CustomRunnable - "+ Thread.currentThread().getId()+" - "+Thread.currentThread().getName() + " - " + str);
        }   
    public CustomRunnable(String str) {
        this.strWorkLoadIdentifier=str;
    }
    public CustomRunnable(String str, String strMessage) {
        this.strWorkLoadIdentifier=str;
        this.strLoadMessage=strMessage;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        log("Starting work Load" + strWorkLoadIdentifier);      
        try {
            long t1=System.currentTimeMillis();
            StaticKafkaBaseSenderImpl.doBackgroundStream(strLoadMessage);
            log("Time taken to post message - " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - t1));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log("Error Sending Message to Kafka");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Class 3: StaticKafkaBaseSenderImpl -> sends message to Kafka Topic.

Application Flow:

1. Main Application thread collects some data.
2. Main Application thread executes below statement:

   CustomExecutorServiceWrapper.submitToSpecificThread(new CustomRunnable("Random MessageId","Collected Data");
3. Main Application thread continues its execution.

While in background inside  method submitToSpecificThread , specific ExecutorService instance is identified and task is submitted to it.

Logs from application run:

```
2019-05-15 14:30:58,595:INFO   :Thread-31_ApplicationProcess: Thread Name - 69 Thread-31_ApplicationProcess queue size 0 [system]: CustomExecutorServiceWrapper
2019-05-15 14:30:58,595:INFO   :Thread-31_ApplicationProcess: FutureObject Cancelledfalse                                  [system]: CustomExecutorServiceWrapper
2019-05-15 14:30:58,595:INFO   :Thread-31_ApplicationProcess: FutureObject isDonefalse                                     [system]: CustomExecutorServiceWrapper
2019-05-15 14:30:58,595:INFO   :Thread-31_ApplicationProcess: Thread Name - 69 Thread-31_ApplicationProcess after submit queue size 0 [system]: CustomExecutorServiceWrapper
```

I added check on Future Object to see if it is getting rejected or cancelled but, I do not see log from `RejectedExecutionHandler` and `isCancelled()` and `isDone()` both returns false.

Comment: what does `jstack` or `jdb` say? can you run them in a terminal on the machine in question?

Comment: I am trying to get access to them, its in a controlled environment. Will update as soon as I have that information.

Comment: Issue was with deployment on specific JVMs. Jars referenced from within runnable were not deployed and exception was not getting raised from Runnable code. As per @gorhawk's suggestion, connected through jdb to proces and realized that class resolution was failing.